# mvn spring:boot fails after running yo jhipster on Mac OS X

Tags: jhipster

`mvn spring:boot` run gives me this error below.

After running you jhipster for the first time on Mac OS X lion.
I have not changed any file at all, just using generated pom.

mvn 3.0.4 and 3.1.1 both tried, java 1.7

```
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 11:22:22-0400)
Maven home: /Users/admin/installs/maven311
Java version: 1.7.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.7.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Error log:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'spring' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/admin/.m2/repository), spring-snapshots (http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot), spring-milestones (http://repo.spring.io/milestone), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 5):

Try running with the following command instead:

> mvn spring-boot:run

(note the dash between spring and boot and the colon between boot and run)